# how pass rel attribute value of a clicked image to method with vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

I am learning vue.js. I would like to pass the value of a rel attribute of an image to a method but I am unable to do that.

This is my html code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <img src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid" id="pc_left" rel="0">
            <img src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid" id="pc_center" rel="0">
            <img src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid" id="pc_right" rel="0">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3 d-flex justify-content-start">
                <img src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid" id="pack_cards" rel="0">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <img src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid invisible" id="pc_game" rel="0">
                <img src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid invisible" id="player_game" rel="0">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 d-flex justify-content-end">
                <img src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid" id="game_briscola" rel="0">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <img @click="play($event)" src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid" id="player_left" rel="5">
            <img @click="play($event)" src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid" id="player_center" rel="6">
            <img @click="play($event)" src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid" id="player_right" rel="7">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is my js function:

```
play(event) {
            var target_id = "#" + event.target.id;
            alert(event.target.rel); //here not working
            var src_image = this.num_to_src(event.target.rel);
            $(target_id).addClass("invisible").removeClass("visible");
            $("#player_game").addClass("visible").removeClass("invisible");
            $("#player_game").attr("src", src_image);
            $("#player_game").attr("rel", event.target.rel);
        }
```

When I try to alert the id or the src everything works fine... but when I alert the rel appears an alert with undefined (I should see a number). No errors appear in the developer tools.

Can someone help?

Comment: You aren't actually doing any data binding via Vue to the rel attributes. You're just manipulating the DOM with jQuery, which doesn't trigger Vue reactivity.

Comment: Is it a bad way of programming with vue.js?

Comment: "Bad" is subjective, but in my experience there is no reason to use jQuery in tandem with a framework like Vue.js or React. jQuery and modern frontend JS frameworks take drastically different approaches to updating a DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getAttribute`

```
event.target.getAttribute("rel")
```